# Refresh part of page in a service worker push event in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, push-notification, react-router, service-worker

I have the following case: I have a web page with antd tabs and I need to refresh each of these tabs  separately in a service worker push event. When I use client.navigate() or client.openWindow() in the event listener the whole page is refreshed. I have found a solution with React Router to pass parameters in the url, but I don't like it because I don't want the url to change and also I need to pass further props to the page that are shared in both tabs. Also how can I manage to call a Route render or a component with props from the service worker file. I use React, Typescript and antd.
The structure is the following:

- Main.tsx - page with Router Routes
- service-worker.ts - service worker methods and functions
- SomePage.tsx - page I need to refresh
- Other pages components etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...

After a little exploring I have used `client.postMessage` in the service worker and on the resulting page I used `navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', (ev))` where I could get the data from the service worker and use it in my component for what I needed and more.